# Do you need both parents' permission to become ordained?

Tags: monasticism, ordination

Do you need both parents' permission to become ordained?

What if one of the parents refuses contact? Should you strive for it?

Comment: You'll have to ask the monastery you wish to ordain at. Some will even ignore a parent's opinion if it's clear that the parent doesn't have the child's best interests at heart.

Comment: Would you post that as an answer, please, Hugh, instead of as a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a question of law. In some places, the laws will allow one parent, or even no parents, since it's a matter of religious preference. In other places, the laws are strict, and require both parents' permission.

This is also a question of the sangha's policies. Most will have an age limit because they observe a need to gain life experience. Some will permit children, and others will even seek after them, so that children will not be unduly influenced by outside ideas. So it depends a lot on who is asking, and who is doing the ordaining.

Ordination can be a big deal. Mostly, though, it's merely feeling a call to serve others, seek the best interests of the world and promote its well-being. Nobody needs an ordination for that, but it helps to have a legal piece of paper to avoid certain troubles.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Theravada Vinaya, one wishing to ordain needs to obtain the permission of all living birth or foster parents, unless they have abandoned him or her.

> A son whose parents have not given their permission. According to the
> Commentary, this requirement includes foster parents as well as birth
> parents. There is no need to get a parent’s permission if he/she is no
> longer alive or has abandoned the son. From this it can be argued that
> if the parents are divorced and one of them has totally abandoned
> responsibility for the son, there is no need to get permission from
> that parent. If, however, both parents continued to assume
> responsibility for the son, **he needs to get the permission of both**.
> [Vinaya on Ordination](https://www.dhammatalks.org/vinaya/bmc/Section0054.html)