# What to do if parents not agree on my willing of becoming a monk?

Tags: parents

I am a 24 year old male and i am very interested in joining a Buddhist monastery and becoming a monk so that i can give my life a right and peaceful purpose. 
But my parents follow Hinduism and think that this religion is superior of all so they don't want me to become a Buddhist and also becoming a Buddhist monk. 
So i don't have their permission to join a Buddhist monastery. They are self dependent and don't need any help from me.

So how can i become a monk?

Comment: The duplicate or previous question do not have a proper answer. I already read that but didn't find the answer.

Comment: According to ruben202's answer, you do need your parent's permission -- that's not the answer you want, but maybe an answer nevertheless. Have you tried asking this question at a monastery?

Comment: See also [Do you need both parents permission to become ordained?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/18286/254)

Comment: It seems a bit odd. I would have thought your parents would be overjoyed and impressed by your dedication and goals. It's a shame they don't like your plan but you're an adult with your own life to lead. Perhaps you could convince them that Buddhism and Hinduism amount to the same thing but it sounds like they wouldn't have much sympathy for this common view.